# What is the difference between JSON.NET DataContractJsonSerializer and the Newtonsoft JSON serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Can someone help me.

What's the difference between the built in JSON.NET DataContractJsonSerializer and the Newtonsoft JSON serializer?

Is it correct that I can use one or the other with Web API and why would I choose one?

Comment: I think you are taking about same thing.

Comment: **Newtonsoft** is the creator/publisher (the company), and **JSON.NET** is the product name. It's the same thing.

Comment: Sorry someone went in and edited my question removing the references to DataContractJsonSerializer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find the comparison of the performance here

[image]
<sub>(source: [newtonking.com](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/media/performance.png))</sub>

Here is the feature comparison,

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm