# Library or reference for using system.data.JSON namespace

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON object array. I am trying to include the Windows.data.JSON namespace and unsuccessful in finding the correct library reference. 
Which library reference I must add to use the namespace.

```
public sealed class JsonArray : IJsonValue,
IList<IJsonValue>,
IEnumerable<IJsonValue>
```

Comment: I've never heard of a `System.Data.JSON` namespace. Did you mean `System.JSON`?

Comment: Sorry its windows.data.Json

Comment: no. I am not using silverlight. Do I have to use ?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.aspx it's a Windows 8 assembly, not Silverlight.

Comment: Guys I am developing a application to load JSON external file and extract data from it. I am using Visual studio and C# winformapplication. Is there some thing wrong in this ?

Answer (score -1):

Add a reference to System.Json. I see it's still in its beta. It covers your windows.data.Json namespace. Thanks!

Comment: I can not find System.Json in the references list

Comment: I am developing it in win7, I think i can use json.net

Comment: Yes, you can. or you can choose newton json.net library for a better performance. Here's some additional information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334930/what-is-the-difference-between-json-net-datacontractjsonserializer-and-the-newto